# woocommerce and printful integration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, integration

I recently downloaded printful on my wordpress website and created an account. I am having this issue come up when trying to sync: Something went wrong with sync. Received error: Error: Sorry, you cannot list resources. [woocommerce_rest_cannot_view]

Can a developer please help me troubleshoot this issue. I will be much appreciative! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that for some reason Printful did not get write access to the Woocommerce REST API.

You could check this out by going to: WooCommerce -> Settings -> Advanced -> REST API

It should look something like this ( except yours probably has an entry for Printful in it):

[REST API tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNGYB.png)

If you see 'read' in the permission row, edit it to be read/write. If there is no entry for Printful here, you will need to add your website on Printful ( at the Stores tab on the website).

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is an important step in the integration process, but I don't believe this fixed it. Thank you though!!